# Explain the mutual exclusion?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Aren't $A$ and $B$ Mutually exclusive? SO why isn't the answer just

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

Comment: Why couldn't you roll a 6 on both rolls?

Comment: Events arent mutually exclusive if they have an element in common. But I don't see why this isnt mutually exclusive @ZacharySelk

Comment: Mutually exclusive means that if one happens then the other can't happen. So if you roll a 6 on the first, why couldn't you roll a 6 on the second?

Comment: You can though  @ZacharySelk . So is that why these arent mutually exclsuive?

Comment: They aren't mutually exclusive, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Sample space

```
 11  12  13  14  15  16
 21  22  23  24  25  26
 31  32  33  34  35  36
 41  42  43  44  45  46
 51  52  53  54  55  56
 61  62  63  64  65  66
```

Event $A$ consists of the 6 points in the last row.
Event $B$ consists of the 6 points in the last column.
Event $A\cap B$ consists of the single point `66`; this is an event 'in common'.
So $A$ and $B$ are not *mutually exclusive* (disjoint).

However, $A$ and $B$ are *independent* because $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B).$
If I am told that a `6` occurred on the first roll, that tells me nothing
about my chances of getting a `6` again on the second roll.

As you begin to study probability, it is important that you not confuse
the concepts of *disjointness* and *independence*.

- Disjointness is a
  logical concept. In a draw from a deck of cards, I can tell you that
  Hearts and Spades are disjoint without knowing anything about whether
  the draw is 'fair'.
- But I can't begin to discuss whether two events
  are independent, unless I know about the probability structure.
  If I know that I'm drawing 'at random' from a full standard deck of 52 cards,
  then I know that Ace and Heart are independent events.